# Fading a picture with sliders [Sencha Touch]

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, slider, fade

I wanted to ask for help cause I can't find any apropriate answers.

I'm developing an app which has 2 modules, one left and one right side that i can enable/disable with a toggle. Each side has a picture with a slider below. The slider has 4 steps which change the pictures. Now I want the pictures to have a fade animation onChange. I can't find an example that comes close enough to my problem.

Here is the code:

```
{
            xtype: 'container',
            name: 'rightContainer',
            flex: 1,
            padding: '2',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    id: 'containerr',
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="boerse_icon1.png" />',
                    margin: 25,
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'sliderfield',
                            id: 'sliderr',
                            disabled: true,
                            value: 0,
                            minValue: 0,
                            maxValue: 3,
                            margin: 25,
                            flex: 1,
                            listeners: {
                                change: function( me, Slider, thumb, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                                    if (newValue == 0) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('containerr').setHtml('<img src="boerse_icon1.png" />');
                                    }
                                    if (newValue == 1) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('containerr').setHtml('<img src="boerse_icon2.png" />');
                                    }
                                    if (newValue == 2) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('containerr').setHtml('<img src="boerse_icon3.png" />');
                                    }
                                    if (newValue == 3) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('containerr').setHtml('<img src="boerse_icon4.png" />');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

this is just the right container. I'm running Sencha Touch framework 2.0

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is basically:

Create a panel with the following layout:

```
layout: {
      type: 'card',
           animation: {
               type: 'fade',
               duration: 2000
           }
       }
```

Then you create a slider with a listener on the `change` event:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(me, Slider, thumb, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        panel.setActiveItem(newValue);                        
    }
}
```

Fill the panel with items (images) and you are good to go.

Just for the sake of it I've put together a working Senchafiddle for you to experiment with:
[**Senchafiddle example**](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#487Kl)

Hopefully this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

May be this work.

```
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                id: 'containerr',
                showAnimation :'fadeIn',
                flex: 1,
                html: '<img src="boerse_icon1.png" />',
                margin: 25,
            },
```

Comment: No, did nothihng. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jannase94 have you tried using "Panel" having "card layout" instead of container. By using it you can easily show various animations.If you want i can provide a basic example of it.

Comment: i want the pictures to be changed by the sliderfield, not by dragging them. Is that possible with card layout?